# how can make my nev bar stay fixed on top with scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html

i tried with `class=navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top` but not happening. i think i can't find the perfect possition to put the class. or is there any js or jq code who can help. please help me with this. Thanks in advance.
my code header code is

```html
<header class="header-wrapper home-opocity">
        <div class="header-aligner">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <div class="header-top-total">
                    <div class="menu-header-top-small-menu-container">
                        <ul id="menu-header-top-small-menu" class="menu">
                             <li id="menu-item-397" class="menu-item menu-
                                  item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                   menu-item-397"><a href="##">Blog</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-398" class="menu-item menu-
                              item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-
                              item-398"><a href="##">Request A Quote</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-399" class="menu-item menu-
                               item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                 menu-item-399"><a href="##">Careers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                <div class="header-bottom-total">
                    <div class="logo-container">
                        <a href="" rel="nofollow">
                            <img src="resource/images/prominute.png" 
                            height="55" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <div class="rmm">
                          <ul id="menu-header_menu" class="menu"> 
                             <li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item menu-
                                item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom 
                                current-menu-item current_page_item menu-
                                item-home menu-item-314"><a 
                                 href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                               <li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-
                                 item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                 menu-item-168"><a 
                                 href="#service">Services</a></li>
                               <li id="menu-item-166" class="menu-item menu-
                                 item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                 menu-item-166"><a 
                                 href="#protfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                               <li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-
                                 item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                 menu-item-177"><a 
                                 href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                               <li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-
                                 item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                 menu-item-177"><a href="#team">Our Team</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-
                                 item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
                                 menu-item-177"><a href="#contact">Contact 
                                 Us</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>      
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
           </header>
```

how can make my nev bar stay fixed on top with scrolling?

Comment: The classes relate to CSS classes, which are used for styling (and positioning) of elements. Without the style sheet definitions of the classes you use, it will be hard to answer your question.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: now worked. i added another nav top fixed class with home-opocity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
.navbar {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
}
```

or using jquery/css

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 0;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

   var stickyNav = function(){
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky'); 
    }
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function() {
 stickyNav();
  });
});
```

Hope this will helps you.